# Is $\vec{v} = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$ Referring to Tangential Speed or Velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I seem to be a bit pedantic when it comes to studying physics. Lately, I have been seeing the equation $\vec{v} = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$, which has been causing me trouble. Shouldn't the right expression give us a scalar value, hence giving us the tangential speed and not the tangential velocity? If $\vec{v}$ is always changing around a circle, how come we find the right expression to be a constant value? I was told that the velocity here referred to the instantaneous velocity, but I couldn't understand why we are using the whole circumference of the circle as the displacement. And what does it mean for displacement to be a circumference, shouldn't that be distance instead?

Hopefully I have been able to address the issue I had in mind.

Comment: Seeing where? Which page?

Comment: One among many: https://youtu.be/DoZ6Sjy4LaU at 8:40 minutes in the video. Of course, it's a YouTube video, but other resources I've seen conveyed the same idea.

Comment: That video has the correct equation $v_t = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$ not $\vec{v} = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$.

Comment: Sorry, it is 8:44 that I meant. Regardless of the notation, the video conveys the idea that tangential velocity is the circumference over the period. I mean not to point out that specific source, since it is always an excellent resource for practicing and the petson behind it works tirelessly to maintain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume $T$ is the period of rotation. $2\pi r/T$ is the *magnitude* of the tangential velocity, i.e. *speed*. The equation
$$\vec v = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$$
doesn't make much sense, because the right hand side is not a vector. $r$ on the right hand side is not the displacement vector: it is the magnitude of the displacement vector measured from the center of rotation, or in other words, the radius of the circle on which the body is rotating.

The equation $v = 2\pi r/T$ is easy to interpret. Every period $T$, the body traverses a distance of $2 \pi r$ (the circumference of the circle; again, this is not a displacement), so the speed is this distance divided by the period.

If you wish to express the instantaneous tangential velocity as a vector quantity, it can be written as
$$ \vec v = \vec \omega \times \vec r $$
where $\vec r$ is the displacement vector with respect to the center of rotation, and $\vec \omega$ is the [angular velocity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) with magnitude $\omega=2\pi/T$.

Answer (score 0):

While the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ remains constant in an orbit, its *direction* is in a constant state of change, thus the use of the vector sign. The direction will always be tangent to the orbit at any given time, which is what gives rise to this 'instantaneous velocity': the constant speed *and* its direction at any instant.

Indeed, you don't need to compute this as a vector, and wikipedia has an entire article on ['orbital speed'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed) . It all comes down to convention of notation, what you are doing, and who you're doing it for. The math stays the same.

Now, for the equation $$v=\frac{2\pi r}{T}$$

we can easily see that we are using the orbital circumference as a 'distance' and orbital period as our 'time', which is chosen for convenience as it is much easier to measure one period, and one circumference than it is to measure some fraction of that.

Now you can *choose* to express this orbital speed $v$ at any given instant, as an instantaneous velocity $\vec{v}$, which is equivalent in magnitude, but tack on whatever direction its going in that moment (a tangent to its orbital path). I normally choose not to, but maybe it becomes important when you consider scenarios like a ball on a string that detaches at some moment, and flies off at tangential velocity $\vec{v}$.